# Service Cloud: When I open a case from a view, it opens as a subtab

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects

I'm in a sandbox environment and trying to configure a service cloud console. I have a view with cases, as such:

[image: Case view]

Everytime I try to click on the case number it opens it as a subtab through accounts, as such:

[image: Subtab]

I haven't done any coding myself. From what I understood this happens in the coding of custom objects, but aren't both cases and accounts standard objects? Where would I need to look to find the relevant code in order to change if it opens as a sub tab or as a primary tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the console app you can setup how records are display.
You can choose between primary tab or a subtab. For cases the default setting is "As a subtab of: Account". Try to set it to "As a primary tab".

To get this settings go to "Setup > Apps > Console" and click on "Edit".

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! No idea how I missed that. Much appreciated!